# Changing the color of the bezier curve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, bezier

Following is the code am using to free hand drawing. But every time i change the color of the brush, new color is applied to the previous curves also. Why is this happening.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {

for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) {

    [brushPattern setStroke];

    _path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

    [_path stroke]; 

  }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

isEdited=YES;

myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

myPath.lineWidth=lineWidths;

CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

[myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

[myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x+1, touchPoint.y+1)];

[pathArray addObject:myPath];

[self setNeedsDisplay];


}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

[myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

[self setNeedsDisplay];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're redrawing all of your paths in drawRect, all with the same colour (brushPattern). If you have paths of different colours, you have to store the colour in use at the time of drawing and set that as your stroke colour in your drawing loop.

I'd suggest that your pathArray holds dictionaries, each dictionary having a path and a colour, instead of just holding paths.

Comment: I have added NSMutableDictionary and added   [dict setObject:brushPattern forKey:myPath]; [pathArray addObject:dict]; in touches begin. How can i iterate over in the drawrect ?

Comment: I did add the color and path in dictionary and that dict in an array.I am getting the different paths and colors in that array, but when i draw the new path previous path gets disappeared even without changing colors. Can any one tell me why is it happening so ?

Comment: Here is my edited question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846064/multiple-coloured-bezier-paths]